# How can i restart a SKScene?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I am creating a game. When the game is over I am showing a button "Play again" which, ideally, should just reload the Scene.

```
var viewSize = currentScene.view?.bounds.size
let sceneG = Level1(size: viewSize!)
currentScene.view?.presentScene(sceneG)
```

but unfortunately, I am getting this error:

> Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent:

Because some nodes already exist in the Scene and is not possible to add them again.

Is there a way to reload the scene or removing all nodes before presenting the scene again?

Thank you

---

As requested, this is the Level1 class:

```
import SpriteKit
import CoreMotion

class Level1: SKScene {

  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
   //creation of nodes etc
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your Level1 initialiser returning the same object?

Comment: @InderKumarRathore Yes, Level1 is the SKScene class that is presented and that I would like to reload

Comment: Can you post the `Level1()` method?

Comment: @InderKumarRathore I have updated my question with Level1 details. but I don't think it can help you

Comment: Yes you're right there is nothing to see :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to remove all children of a scene, use this `func removeAllChildren()`.

Look at the [SKNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/removeAllChildren) docs under Working with Node Trees.

Comment: Thanks! Removing all children solved my problem! :-)